# Counting columns in the same table

Tags: sql, database, vba, aggregate-functions, column-count

I've been trying to develop a cashflow statement in access 2007. This would be so easily done in excel using formulas such as

```
= SUM (B6:M6) / CountIF(B6:M6)>0
```

but I cant seem to wrap my head around this when it comes to access. And I need this for every company we enter data on. The cashflow statement is supposed to look like this (Since I can't yet post a pic):

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Particulars | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec | Average |
Sales---------------------->
Salary------>
Transportation----->
```

and about 10 other items in the row, all with entries for Jan till Dec, however, sometimes we take 6 months worth of data and sometimes for all 12 months. (Imagine a basic excel sheet with items on the first column and headers for the next 12-13 columns).

In access, I made tables for each Item with columns as the months, eg. tblRcpt--> |rcpt_ID|Jan|Feb|... and so on till dec for all the items. Then  they will be arranged and presented in an entry form which would be designed to look similar to the above table while later I would query and link them together to presentthe complete cashflow statement.

Now comes the question, I need to Average together the columns (as you can see in the right most column), BUT I only want to average together those months that have been filled (Sometimes in accounting people enter '0' where there is no data), so I cant just sum the columns and divide by twelve. It has to be dynamic, all functions seem to center around counting and averaging ROWs, not COLUMNs.

Thanks for just bearing with me and reading this, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The reason you're having trouble is because a database is **not** a spreadsheet. Your structure is not normalized, and SQL statements don't work well with denormalized tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
(Jan + Feb + ... + Dec) /
  ( case when Jan = 0 then 0 else 1 end
  + case when Feb = 0 then 0 else 1 end

  + case when Dec = 0 then 0 else 1 end )
as Avg
```

Comment: I'll try it, but where should I type the VBA? should I do that in a form and then store the result in the table?

Comment: I've tried the Case method but couldn't get the syntaxes right. So I used a simple IF, else statement for all the months. Thanks a bunch! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your table structure should be:

```
Particulars | Month | Amount
Sales         1       500
Sales         2       1000
Salary        1       80000
```

...and so on. You can either *not* enter rows when you don't have a value for that month, or you can handle them in the SQL statement (as I have below):

```
SELECT Particulars, AVG(Amount) AverageAmount
FROM MyTable
WHERE NULLIF(Amount, 0) IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Particulars;
```

Comment: I knew there was something wrong when I had to make so many individual tables for each item and repeating 12 months of column  for all of them. But I'm not certain how the structure you suggested  works? Do you think I should make monhts as a foreign key? I'm trying to make this in access because there will be hundreds of company's cashflow statements that will need to be entered here by several users from the front end. Could you please elaborate a little?